# Find specific TEXT between Small brackets using FIND with wildcard

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word, wildcard

I need to find specific Text say `" PL"` between small brackets `()` i.e

Text Criteria:

1. text " PL" - both letters are Capital and there is a space before "PL"
2. text should be bold
3. text should be in between small brackets ie. ()

Example Text:

1. Portugues SA (**BCP PL, Buy**): (Target Price: €0.22) Bank
2. Jeronimo Martins SGPS SA (**JMT PL, Buy**): (Target Price: €19.60) 2Q21 Review
3. Ibersol SGPS SA (**IBS PL, Neutral**): (Target Price: €6.50) Cinven acquires controlling

VBA Code:

```
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "\((.*?)\)" ' WhildCard
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
    End With
    If Selection.Find.Found Then

    'if found then need to select the paragraph and do something with it.

    End If
```

If it is possible using `Wildcard`, please help

[image]

Comment: Are there three examples, or only one containing three lines?

Comment: those three lines containing specific text that I need to find. the text is " PL" that is between ( *********):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub test1()
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find 'or Selection.Range.Find
        .Text = "\(?*\)"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute
            If InStr(.Parent.Text, " PL") And .Parent.Font.Bold Then
                'do something with it
                .Parent.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

### Edit2 pattern without parentheses

```
Sub test2()
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .Text = " PL"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute
            If .Parent.Font.Bold Then
                .Parent.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: how do I select and cut the whole paragraph which agrees with my situation?

Comment: See edited code: `.Parent.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete`

Comment: Great!what if need to exclude the brackets? ONLY text should be highlight red?

Comment: Excude from search pattern?

Comment: yes! as it searches the text but excludes the brackets.

Comment: See Edit2 option